# How to change GIT diff-config on Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, diff, git-diff, azure-repos

I can ignore GIT file renames on my local machine by adding following line to `.git/config`

```
[diff]
    renames = false
```

Is it possible to configure this on the Azure DevOps Repos ? We want to use the built in diff viewer of DevOps without it suggesting file renames.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the Azure DevOps Repo doesn't support ignore renaming files.

Currently displaying the rename file in the Azure DevOps repo diff viewer is the default behavior, we can't change it for now.

I suggest that you can create [a suggestion feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion)  to report the  feature requirement.